# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' android

Tags: android, gallery

I want to use this source code of gallery in android studio

> git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery

but i got this error please how i fix it ? i try all solutions without any goal !


here is the message

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

please how i fix it because i need this source of gallery , also if it not possible to fix this error please can anyone give me source of any gallery.

thanks in advance

Here is the gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.gallery"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform following steps to solve this error:

1. Just clean the project
   (sometimes i clean the project and this problem is solved automatically)
2. if first step doesn't work then this is the error of buildToolsVersion. You can add right buildToolsVersion from:

   ```
   just click on
   ```

   -> **File**

   -> **Project Structure**

   -> **app (just single click on "app", this is under "Modules")**

   Here you will see the buildToolsVersion under the Properties and just select right buildToolsVersion and click ok.

After this You can synchronice and I hope that error will be solved.